# Sony Experia E5 microphone only produces static when I talk

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, audio, calls, sony-xperia, microphone

I noticed that in my last two phone calls noone was able to hear me talk. I tried to send a Whatsapp voice message. When I listened to it, I discovered that when I talk the only thing that can be heard is some weird static noise.

Is this a known problem or has anyone else experienced it? And if yes do you know how to fix it? 
This happened out of the blue - my phone didn't recently fall or anything like that it worked fine until it just stopped working fine. The android version is Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Answer (score 0):

Rub over the microphone hole with a magnet.

This will work if there is metallic dust stuck to your microphone, or if the cone is stuck inverted. The magnet can dislodge the metallic dust and force the cone to move.

If that doesn't work, bring the device in to a repair facility. It might be physically damaged.